# 3 way relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've exhausted searching and reading through potential solutions, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it, so i'm hoping someone here might help me!

I have three models: Clients, Services and Users.

- A Client has many Services
- and Services belong to many Clients.
- Users can have many Services through a Client.

Real world example:

- Client (Company XYZ) has these available Services (payments, invoicing, time tracking).
- User (Bob) is assigned to the Client (Company XYZ)
- and for this specific Client, he has access to the payments and invoicing Services.

Pictured below is the DB design (it doesn't have to be implemented exactly as this).

What would be the best approach to implement this? A custom pivot table?

[image]

Comment: What is the issue with the current implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Does your relationship really need to be that complicated? Is there ever a case where a User would be assigned a Client, but not have any Services?

If no, then this is just a simple many-to-many relationship between the ClientServices and Users tables, and you can drop the UserClient table.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the services are independently assigned to the user, the user wouldn't automatically have all the services available to the client (hasManyThrough).

Therefore, a user_services table could contain the services assigned to that user, with an extra field for client_id to indicate who they are assigned the service through.

The relationship in Eloquent just being belongsToMany between users and services and you'd need to query the client id on that relationship.  Simply:

```
public function getServices($client) {
    return $this->services()->where('client_id', $client->id)->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The problem with doing this is that I can no longer do something like this: $user->clients->services

Comment: $user->clients should be a collection of related client models, not objects representing the user client relationship.  (Essentially, the objects in Client::get() and $user->clients should be of the same type)  Are you looking for a model that represents a UserClient relationship?  I suppose that is possible, but I've never done it.  You normally don't have models for pivot tables.